# How to dynamically add data to google maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have got a map that I want to have a feed of lat/long data getting pushed to the map data array. I have the function to get the data, but am having trouble getting that to be usable in the map data array.

The idea is to have a new marker drop in when a new coordinate is added to the array. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
   var ID='0';
        var DATA=[];
        function getData(){
            var url = 'http://us7.fieldagent.net/api/newResponses/';
            //url = 'http://us7.fieldagent.net/api/newResponses/;
            $.post(url,{'id':ID},function(data){
                if(data.status_id == 0){
                    ID = data.id;
                    console.log('Last Id: '+data.id);
                    var new_data = data.responses;

                    var count = 0
                    $.each(new_data,function(i,v){
                        count += 1;
                        var coord = 'new google.maps.LatLng('+v.lat+','+v.lon+'),';
                        DATA.push(coord);
                    })
                    console.log('Added '+count+' responses..')
                }
            });
        }
    $(document).ready(function(){
                getData();
                setInterval(getData,20*1000);
            });

        function drop() {
                for (var i = 0; i < DATA.length; i++) { 
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            addMarker();
                        }, i * 500);
                    }
                } 

        function addMarker(){
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                position: DATA[iterator],
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                icon: 'fatie.svg',
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            }));
            iterator++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually add the item to the map.  Right now, you're only adding an item to your `DATA` array.  You need to call `addMarker` with the new data as well.

You seem to want to add these markers to the map at an interval so they drop onto the map over time, while also being able to query for new markers from your server.

Try code like this:

```
var ID='0';
var DATA=[];
function getData(){
    var url = 'http://us7.fieldagent.net/api/newResponses/';
    $.post(url,{'id':ID},function(data){
        if(data.status_id == 0){
            ID = data.id;
            console.log('Last Id: '+data.id);
            var new_data = data.responses;

            var count = 0
            $.each(new_data,function(i,v){
                count += 1;
                var coord = 'new google.maps.LatLng('+v.lat+','+v.lon+'),';
                DATA.push(coord);
            });
            console.log('Added '+count+' responses..');
            if (count > 0) addMarker(); //call addMarker if there are new markers
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    getData();
    setInterval(getData,20*1000);
});

function addMarker(){
    if (DATA.length == 0) return; //exit if DATA is empty
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: DATA.shift(), //take the first item in DATA
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        icon: 'fatie.svg',
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    }));
    if (DATA.length > 0) setTimeout(addMarker, 500); //call again if needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Method which does two things.

1. Add to the Array
2. Add the Item to the map

Comment: 1. Isn't that what DATA.push(coord); is doing?

Comment: Also, the function 'addMarker' adds the new data points to the map.

When I have a static data array, the addMarker and drop functions work perfectly.

Comment: Your DATA array is only that, an array with coordinates. To actually add them to the map you have to take them from the array and add them. Thats a seperate step. Just because they are in the array won´t make them appear on the map. My approach: Create a method which takes a coordinate and a) adds it to the array b) add it to the map. Thats it. See @jeffs answer for a slightly different solution.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasS. Got it to work! But now I am getting a flicker right before the drop animation. I have seen some documentation about this, but it seems to be "fixed" in one of the API updates. Does it have anything to do with my .svg icon?