# Is It Possible To Manipulate a Google Map that is NOT on your site?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm reading the google maps documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API/) and all of the code examples involve creating a **new** map on your page.

Can I not create a saved google map, and push data to this programmatically?

The use case is data being automatically added upon a form submission, and that map being linked to publically

Comment: What you would usually have is a page with a google map and data that comes from a database, so that when someone submits new data, next time user loads map it will have that data included.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624779/how-to-dynamically-add-data-to-google-maps-api This link might help u get the answer wat u r looking for.

Comment: I'm confused. If the map is not on your site, where is it then? Is it somewhere in your PCs hard disk? Is it on someone else's site?

Comment: I was under the impression that I could save a google map and later access it by ID. 

I must have been mistaken

Comment: Do you mean saving it in Google servers, just like you save stuff in pastebin.com and then retrieve it by some random ID?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Can that be done?

Comment: No, that can't be done. Google Maps is an API, not an storage or hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save Google Maps. 
You can however create you own map via the api and then add data via javascript so it will only show the data you enter.

I would:

Use the Google Maps Api in a Frame.
Then add a Markers to the DB.
On Page reload or AJAX you can add a new Marker.

Comment: Thanks!

I think I'll be going with this. I'll wait until it's tested and built to mark it as resolved though